# Set dual screen on Fedora

Tags: fedora, xfce, multi-monitor

I would like to set dual screen mode on my Fedora 18 XFCE (what I mean is that I want to be able to display different content on every screen). Currently my screens shows the same, i.e. the secondary one is the mirroring primary one. I have a laptop plugged into the docking station with other monitor if that matters.

I actually tried to play with `xrandr` but didn't succeed. This command

`xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1` does what I want but I still can't drag and drop applications between the screens

Comment: Video card, probably driver used and similar info would be helpfull...

Comment: As I recall you can use the "Display" or "Monitor" tool found under the settings menu. I also recall that I needed to set some offset to align the screens in the way you want.

Comment: @IBr I got Nvidia with nouveau drivers

Comment: Don't you just use the nvidia configuration tool to set these up `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`? http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/images/NVidia-settings-XserverDisplayConfiguration.png

Comment: I think if you are going with nouveau, you can use xrandr tools and/or xinerama. I think this could be helpfull, though not fedora specific, but it should work: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#Xinerama.2C_TwinView_and_separate_screens

Comment: What exactly does the `xrandr` command you tried do? It should spread your desktop over the two screens (with VGA1 being the left-most and LVDS1 extending the desktop to the right). You should then be able to take a window from VGA1 and drag it to the right until it appears on LVDS1. What results are you getting? How many mouse pointers do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with `xrandr --output LVDS1 --left-of VGA1`, this works as I expected.

Comment: Old thread but I would like to point out that if you are using virtual box the outputs will be VBOX0 and VBOX1 instead of LVDS1 and VGA1.